# how to initialize immutable val with scala without creating another val

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
private def formatQuery(q:String = ""):String = {
  val q2 = if (q=="") "*" else "'%s'".format(q)
  [...]
```

I'd just like to know if there's some idiomatic way to avoid declaring the q2 value

someting like

```
private def formatQuery(
  q:String = if (q=="") "*" else "'%s'".format(q)
):String = {
  [...]
```

which obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are trying to avoid assigning to a variable `q2`?  The style itself seems fine.

What you proposed obviously doesn't work, but here are two suggestions that would work.

If your original function is:

```
private def formatQuery(q:String = ""):String = {
  val q2 = if (q=="") "*" else "'%s'".format(q)
  doSomething(q2)
}
```

One option is to just pass the if-else expression where you would pass `q2`:

```
private def formatQuery(q:String = ""):String =
  doSomething(if (q=="") "*" else "'%s'".format(q))
```

Another is to make a separate function:

```
private def formatQuery(q:String = ""):String =
  runQuery(if (q=="") "*" else "'%s'".format(q))

private def runQuery(q2:String):String =
  doSomething(q2)
```

Comment: I just don't like having to define a new val, when in fact I'm just trying to inialize q... Just a matter of style, and to find out if Scala provided a more elegant way to do it...

Comment: There are no mutable variables in your method (ie, nothing declared with `var`).  You should avoid using `var`, and you have done so successfully.  I see no reason why you should add one.  Your use of `val`, however, is totally fine because it is immutable.

Comment: oops, sorry dhg, just deleted the prior comment because I didn't understood well you question...

Answer (score 2):

A third way is pattern matching.

```
private def formatQuery(q: String = ""): String = q match {
  case _ if q.length == 0 => "*"
  case _ => "'%s'".format(q)
}
```

I prefer the way you did it, first because it is good style.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a misunderstanding: The *val* inside of the method body is not a field of the enclosing class or trait or ..., but it is just a local variable. So the keyword *val* is used for creating fields **and** for creating local variables.